# How to display details in one to many relationship

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my case, one maincategory has many subcategories.

maincategory model defined:

```js
const MainCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  mainCategoryName: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

subcategory model defined

```js
const SubCategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  subCategoryName: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  main_category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "MainCategory",
  },
});

module.exports.getAllSubCategories = function (callback) {
  SubCategory.find(callback);
};
```

route

```js
router.get( "/subCategories",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    SubCategory.getAllSubCategories((err, subCategory) => {
      if (err) {
        let message = "No category";
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message,
        });
      } else {
        return res.send(subCategory);
      }
    });
  }
);
```

How can I display mainCategoryName along with subCategoryName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate `main_category` like this:

```js
router.get("/subCategories",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    SubCategory.find()
      .populate("main_category")
      .exec((err, subCategory) => {
        if (err) {
          let message = "No category";
          return res.json({
            success: false,
            message
          });
        } else {
          return res.send(subCategory);
        }
      });
  }
);
```

Comment: but how can I get mainCategoryName its provide the same result that find() method provides  "_id": "5e85ac5e9e82215ae4010560",
        "subCategoryName": "Tshirt",
        "main_category": "5e844c16a0e4c74f6cc4c0c2",
        "__v": 0

Comment: Can you add a sample SubCategory and MainCategory document to the question?

Comment: **yes**   ` "_id": "5e85ac5e9e82215ae4010560",
        "subCategoryName": "Tshirt",
        "main_category": "5e844c16a0e4c74f6cc4c0c2",
        "__v": 0` this the result I got same as find()

Comment: @Rahul it may be a problem with your document's values? Can you add  a sample SubCategory and MainCategory document to the question?

Comment: @Rahul please add your mongodb documents in json format

Comment: @SulemanSah https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgjR0WTMq4sigyC7N5kf7icnZRPq?e=d2qpFi

Comment: @Rahul is it difficult to add your question by editing?

Comment: @SulemanSah your above code worked. It's my mistake that it's not worked early